# LWC Component cannot see Nested query

Tags: lightning-web-components, nested

I'm having an issue showing nested apex query inside LWC result.

```
return [SELECT Id, Name, Last_Maintenance_Date__c, Location__c,(SELECT Id, Date__c FROM 
        Maintenances__r)
        FROM Car__c
        WHERE Id IN (SELECT Car__c FROM Maintenance__c WHERE Date__c = NEXT_N_WEEKS:2)
        ];
```

LWC return me this
[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you try to log on to console `address.Maintenances__r`. Also, if the case of the `Maintenances__r` is correct as its case sensitive